# Why does each process folder under /proc contain the same information?

Tags: kernel, proc

Under `/proc/<PID>/net` pseudo-file system each process seems to have files with the same content. For example I use `cat /proc/<PID>/net/ip_tables_names` to list iptables tables under the system and content of this file is same for all the processes. Same is true for other files in `/proc/<PID>/net` directory. Why is this so?

Comment: They wouldn't if they were running in a different network namespace (like in containers or if you use `ip netns`).